# C++ Class Template Constructor inheritance with pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, constructor

I currently have the following Circularly Doubly Linked List as the parent (provided by the professor of my class):

```
template <class datatype>
class CDLL
{
public:
    struct node;
    class iterator;

    // Constructors
    CDLL(void);
    CDLL(unsigned int n_elements, datatype datum);
    CDLL(const CDLL& rlist);
    CDLL(iterator begin, iterator end);

    // .. code ...

};
```

Our instructions were to create a Queue that inherits from this CDLL:

```
template <class datatype>
class Queue : protected CDLL<datatype> {
public:
    using CDLL<datatype>::CDLL;

    // ... code ...
};
```

In my tests I have:

```
Queue<int> x = Queue<int>(2, 1); // Creates a queue of: [1, 1]
Queue<int> * y = &Queue<int>(2, 1); // Creates a queue of: []
```

I have debugged this thoroughly and it walks through the constructor steps (pushing each element to the queue/cdll) and it walks through every step. When it pops out of the `cdll` constructor, it "forgets" everything it's done. The address of `this` in the `cdll` constructor matches the address of `y`. I've also tried `Queue<datatype>::Queue() : Queue::CDLL<datatype>() {}` but the same behavior persists.

I've taken a look at:

[C++ Inheritance constructor override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112665/c-inheritance-constructor-override), [What are the rules for calling the superclass constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/what-are-the-rules-for-calling-the-superclass-constructor) and a few other questions with titles similar to this one but I can't seem to explain the behavior of this.

I have surfed google/SO and have tried many of the solutions many have suggested but to no avail.

Comment: Why in the name of Bjarne Stroustrup would you do: `Queue<int> * y = &Queue<int>(2, 1);`?? ... That is not a legal declaration in C++.

Comment: `&Queue<int>(2, 1)` shouldn't compile. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @WhiZTiM Later, we're to create a `Queue` that publicly inherits from `CDLL` and to be able to create an array of `CDLL` pointers that contain both queues and `cdll`s

Comment: @Quentin I am currently using VS2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Queue<int> * y = &Queue<int>(2, 1);
```

Is not valid C++. It is apparently accepted by an MSVC extension. The issue is that, while this extension allows you to take the address of the temporary, it does not extend its lifetime; which means that this instance of `Queue<int>` is destructed as soon as the initialization of `y` is completed, leaving `y` dangling and its further inspection via the debugger nonsensical.

To disable MSVC extensions, [use the `/Za` compiler switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions).

Comment: What if I were to create an array of `**cdll` where I want to place queues and `cdlls`?

Comment: @npengra317 `CDLL<int> *p = &x;` works fine, via implicit pointer conversion. You will also probably get to dynamic memory allocation and smart pointers before dealing with collections of polymorphic objects (such as an array owning `Queue`s and `CDLL`s).

Comment: Understood, I will cite this to my professor. Thank you for your help.